# UICollectionViewCell not updating view after selection

Tags: ios, uicollectionview

Have an issue where:

```
override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath)
```

is called when an item is *selected*, but I cannot change any cell properties from this method.

I created a new project with a stripped down UICollectionViewController to change the background color of a cell when selected.  It also doesn't work.  Here it is:

```
import UIKit

private let reuseIdentifier = "Cell"

class CollectionViewController: UICollectionViewController {

override func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 5
}

override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath)

    cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue

    return cell
}

override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let cell = self.collectionView(self.collectionView, cellForItemAt: indexPath)
    cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.green
}
```

}

The only thing I did in Storyboard is delete the standard View Controller and replace it with a UICollectionViewController, create a subclass of UICollectionViewController and set the controller in the storyboard as that class.

Also, I can confirm that the cell's index path is returned from this method when called from inside the `didSelectItemAt` method:

```
self.collectionView.indexPathsForSelectedItems
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the wrong API. **Never** call the delegate method `collectionView(_ cellForItemAt:`, use `cellForItem(at:`

```
if let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) {
   cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.green
}
```

But be aware that this change is not persistent. When the user scrolls the color will change back to blue.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that as below,

**ViewController**

```
override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "ColoursViewCell", for: indexPath) as! ColoursViewCell
    return cell
}
```

**UICollectionViewCell**

```
class ColoursViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    @IBOutlet var photoImageView: UIImageView?

    override var bounds: CGRect {
        didSet {
            self.layoutIfNeeded()
        }
    }

    override var isSelected: Bool{
        didSet{
            if self.isSelected{
                self.photoImageView?.backgroundColor = UIColor.random
            }else{
                self.photoImageView?.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGray
            }
        }
    }
}
```

you can have sample projects from this link I have in GitHub
https://github.com/hadanischal/RandomColors/tree/develop